# Matplotlib histogram showing wrong predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib, histogram

I am making use of **matplotlib** to plot frequency of occurrences in a python list, but it is plotting for the values not present in the list

widthList:

```
3.1622776601683795, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 0.0, 4.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.1622776601683795, 3.1622776601683795, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 0.0, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 4.242640687119285, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.47213595499958, 8.0, 9.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 4.242640687119285, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.1622776601683795, 3.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 3.0, 3.1622776601683795, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 1.4142135623730951, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1622776601683795, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.605551275463989, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 3.1622776601683795, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 3.1622776601683795, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.1622776601683795, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.605551275463989, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 3.1622776601683795, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.8284271247461903, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979, 2.23606797749979]
```

here we can clearly see that there's not even a single **7** but the histogram shows weird outputs:
[image: histogram]

code:

```
 width_frequency = Counter(','.join([str(i) for i in widthList])).most_common(6)
    print(width_frequency)
    width = [widths for widths, _ in width_frequency]
    freq = [counts for _, counts in width_frequency]
    #
    plt.bar(width, freq)
    plt.ylabel("Frequency")
    plt.xlabel("Width")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
width_frequency = Counter(','.join([str(i) for i in widthList])).most_common(6)
```

i.e you are converting the list to a `,` separated string and passing the whole string to counter which will just counter the number of occurrences of characters in your input:

```
Counter(','.join([str(i) for i in widthList]))
```

output:

```
Counter({',': 1789,
         '.': 1790,
         '0': 1792,
         '1': 1252,
         '2': 3492,
         '3': 1559,
         '4': 1904,
         '5': 403,
         '6': 1950,
         '7': 3636,
         '8': 587,
         '9': 3357})
```

#### Fix:

Pass the list of numbers

```
width_frequency = Counter(widthList).most_common(6)
```

[image]

#### Using histogram:

```
plt.hist(widthList, bins=10, rwidth = 0.8)
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Width")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! thanks for explaining this so nicely...just another question, can these bars be spaced out?

Comment: @arizona_3 `Histograms` are meant for this, you do not have to use counters. Updated the anser.